# Parse Anypic Facebook login error

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, facebook-login

I am exprimenting with Parse's Anypic and I keep getting these 3 errors:

```
Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <PAPWelcomeViewController>
```

then goes

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController>
```

and finally

```
Login failure. FB Access Token or user ID does not exist
```

I'm setting everything up just as it was stated in the tutorial. It was working fine in the past and I wasn't getting these errors, however when I came back to the project after some time I am getting these.

They are happening while trying to log in to the app through Facebook. I select login, put my details, click login and then nothing happens, it just goes back to the "log in with facebook" button.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you share the essential bits of your code?

Comment: Everything is pretty much default. I just addedd Parse applictation id and client key in AppDelegate.m, and facebook app details in info.plist

Comment: Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to change handleFacebookSession to look like this:

```
- (void)handleFacebookSession {
if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(logInViewControllerDidLogUserIn:)]) {
        [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(logInViewControllerDidLogUserIn:) withObject:[PFUser currentUser]];
    }
    return;
}

NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"public_profile",
                               @"user_friends",
                               @"email"];

self.hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

// Login PFUser using Facebook
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {

    if (!user) {
        NSString *errorMessage = nil;
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            errorMessage = @"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.";
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
            errorMessage = [error localizedDescription];
        }
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log In Error"
                                                        message:errorMessage
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
        }

        if (!error) {
            [self.hud removeFromSuperview];
            if (self.delegate) {
                if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(logInViewControllerDidLogUserIn:)]) {
                    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(logInViewControllerDidLogUserIn:) withObject:user];
                }
            }
        } else {
            [self cancelLogIn:error];
        }
    }
}];}
```

Solution was taken from [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Anypic/issues/43)